# Name These Animals

Tags: number-sequence, animals

Can you definitively name these animals?

More importantly, can you find and extend the hidden number sequence?

1. With elegant, long ears, precious huge animals need to be protected.
2. Winter predator often found loping across frozen tundra.
3. You shouldn't call them *puny!* They're obviously small, nice animals yearning to fit in.
4. If lost at birth, a newborn one might just say "ba-a-a-!"
5. While not actually blind, they can also see with their ears.
6. These aviators are believed to be essential to our ecosystem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The words are

> 1. Elephant: With **e**legant, **l**ong **e**ars, **p**recious **h**uge **a**nimals **n**eed **t**o be protected.
> 2. Wolf: **W**inter predator **o**ften found **l**oping across **f**rozen tundra.
> 3. Pony: You shouldn't call them **p**uny! They're **o**bviously small, **n**ice animals **y**earning to fit in.
> 4. Lamb: If **l**ost at birth, **a** newborn one **m**ight just say "**b**a-a-a-!"
> 5. Bat: While not actually **b**lind, they can **a**lso see with **t**heir ears.
> 6. Bee: These aviators are **b**elieved to be **e**ssential to our **e**cosystem.

I imagine the number pattern is

> related to the words used to make the animal name (skipping stuff at the beginning and end occasionally), every word for the first one, every second word for the following two, and the every third word for the last three. (Thanks El-Guest)

And so perhaps the next line could be

> 7. Equipped **w**ith long tusks, this **a**nimal also possesses a **l**ayer of protective blubber, **r**endering the cold waters **u**nder which it swims **s**afe for passage.

Comment: You should look at the spacing between used words — the first answer uses every word, the next two answers use every second word, the next three answers after that use every third word....

Comment: You get the coveted green walrus of acceptance! I was looking for an answer of rot13(bar,gjb,gjb,guerr,guerr,guerr,sbhe,sbhe,sbhe,sbhe), but your additional line was very entertaining.